# Convert a CSS selector to HTML

Tags: code-golf

A CSS selector is made up of five elements:

1. The element type (tag name)
2. The id of the element
3. The classes of the element
4. The attributes of the element
5. Operators to chain these element selectors

This challenge will only involve the first four--also taking into account operators would make more than one element be generated and that's a bit too complex for this challenge. Maybe a future one. ;)

**Input**: A CSS selector, not including any operators. The element type will always be present, but the rest of the portions may not be.

**Output**: An html element representing the selector.

**Examples**:

```
In: div
Out: <div></div>

In: div[with-data="cool-data"][foo]
Out: <div with-data="cool-data" foo></div>

In: span.nice.tidy.cool
Out: <span class="nice tidy cool"></span>

In: button#great-button.fancy[data-effect="greatness"]
Out: <button id="great-button" class="fancy" data-effect="greatness"></button>

In: custom-element#secret[secret-attribute="secret value!!"]
Out: <custom-element id="secret" secret-attribute="secret value!!"></custom-element>

In: element#id.class1.class2[attribute1][foo="bar"]
Out: <element id="id" class="class1 class2" attribute1 foo="bar"></element>
```

- You may assume that the input selector will always have the different parts in order (element type, id, class, attributes).
- You may assume that the provided attribute selectors will never be an attribute text search (^=, $=, *=).
- You may assume that the input word characters (element type, attribute names, class names, ids) will always match the regex [a-z0-9_-]
- You may have extra whitespace anywhere *except* for inside strings (attribute values)

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer (in bytes) wins. [Standard loop-holes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061) apply.

Comment: Are spaces valid input in the selector? I.e., `div div.test` => `<div><div class="test"></div></div>`

Comment: No, I would count that as an operator. Would also make the challenge much harder. Maybe for a follow-up challenge ;)

Comment: Can we aasume that the elements willonly be lowercase letters, digits, or '-'-?

Comment: Yes, you may assume that.

Comment: I think `ids` and `classes` are `attributes` of HTML elements, right?

Comment: In the output are multiple separating spaces allowed? e.g. `...id="id"[space 3 times]class="class"...`

Comment: @IvankaTodorova yes, they are, technically. `#` and `.` are just another syntax for them

Comment: @GáborFekete Yes, that's fine

Comment: Can we assume that if the selector contains a class, it must also contain an id and that if it contains an attribute, it must also contain a class? If not, could you add another test case or 2 to cover that?

Comment: I added the new cases, thanks for the suggestion @Shaggy

Comment: Second example's `with-data` attribute shouldn't be `with=data` in the output.

Comment: All of the parts 1-4 are optional in CSS including #1, the element tag. So `#info.sorted` is a valid CSS descriptor, but the element name is not present. Your test cases don't cover this. Are we to assume some default element type in this case? Maybe `div`? Or maybe we can assume the element name will always be present for this challenge?

Comment: The element name will always be present in this challenge, for simplicity.

Comment: You can have extra whitespace anywhere except for inside attribute values. @ovs

Comment: What about elements that explicitly don't have a closing tag, like `input`?

Comment: You can ignore their existence. Would overcomplicate the challenge.

Answer (score 5):

## PHP, <strike>125</strike> 119 bytes

```
<?=preg_replace(['/#([\w-]+)/','/\.([^[]+)/','/[.[\]]/','/(\S+).*/'],[' id="$1"',' class="$1"',' ','<$1></$1>'],$argn);
```

Just regex replacements.

Saved 6 bytes thanks to Christoph.

Comment: How does this work for the last test case?

Comment: @Neil It works good [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#PU7BDoMgFLv7FQZJwOkgeFX0I3Z8sAWVOROnBln2@Y64bIembdqkrZr1sUbYuGGWxE72aWefjD3rJrNt4ksFGO/d2L68FRruyyJRaxzSpIyaeq8auTo73JxdJ9NZCoQnFNT7rLOUk5xwxShcFfwsMAVK60NTdclSyk4h0TmQeOwlwgKFKD6W/y6gwgIXdcWxqEP5eJyW@/4B "PHP – TIO Nexus")

Comment: Aha, I see what it's doing now. (All those ``\``s were confusing me.)

Comment: `<?=preg_replace(['/#([\w-]+)/','/\.([^\[]+)/','/[.\[\]]/','/(\S+).*/'],[' id="$1"',' class="$1"',' ','<$0></$1>'],$argn);` should work.

Comment: It seems we don't need to escape `[` within `[]`: `<?=preg_replace(['/#([\w-]+)/','/\.([^[]+)/','/[.[\]]/','/‌​(\S+).*/'],[' id="$1"',' class="$1"',' ','<$0></$1>'],$argn);` another 2 bytes.

Comment: I don't know what happens here but `<?=preg_replace(['/#([\w-]+)/','/\.([^[]+)/','/[.[\]]/','/(\S+).*/'],[' id="$1"',' class="$1"',' ','<$1></$1>'],$argn);` is actually only *119 bytes* and my first tip was only *121 bytes* (we remove `$2()`: 4 bytes). Somehow some unprinted chars seem to get counted when copying from the comment.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>88</s> <s>76</s> 67 bytes

```
#([\w-]+)
 id="$1"
\.([^[]+)
 class="$1"
T`[].` 
^(\w+).*
<$&></$1>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#JctBCoAgFADRvacIlbAiw9blKdp9jawMBCsow@Mb1GrgwSTCQMVaVwXK3NpjKjBSnMEIHy3e3PevwwSaTxkamYpVwUvU0Vx2DRUyJevtbo9A3Mq/Q/ypWzAhXG5@ghUatvPs8WwurF8)

*-10 bytes thanks to @Neil*
*-2 bytes thanks to @KritixiLithos*

Comment: Your result is wrong, it should be `class="class1 class-2"`.

Comment: @Neil fixed it.

Comment: That last `$1$2` can be `$&`; your class check contains unnecessary `()`s; also I think you can optimise some of those single-character replacements into a single `T` operation. (If not, `]` doesn't need to be quoted.)

Comment: `^(\w+)(.*)` can become `^(\w+).*` because the second capturing group is not needed

Comment: `^(\w+).*` can become `(\S+).*` (credits to @user63956).

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 193 bytes

```js
s=>[[/#([\w-]+)/,` id="$1"`],[/((\.[\w-]+)+)/,(_,c)=>` class="${c.split`.`.join` `.trim()}"`],[/(\[.+?\])/g,(_,a)=>" "+a.slice(1,-1)],[/([\S]+)(.*)/,"<$1$2></$1>"]].map(r=>s=s.replace(...r))[3]
```

Longer than most since I preferred to output the HTML with all proper whitespace. Also works with the selector parts out of order (`div[attr].class#id`).

### Test Snippet

```js
f=
s=>[[/#([\w-]+)/,` id="$1"`],[/((\.[\w-]+)+)/,(_,c)=>` class="${c.split`.`.join` `.trim()}"`],[/(\[.+?\])/g,(_,a)=>" "+a.slice(1,-1)],[/([\S]+)(.*)/,"<$1$2></$1>"]].map(r=>s=s.replace(...r))[3]

;["","div",'div[with-data="cool-data"][foo]',"span.nice.tidy.cool",'button#great-button.fancy[data-effect="greatness"]','custom-element#secret[secret-attribute="secret value!!"]','element#id.class1.class2[attribute1][foo="bar"]'].forEach(s => S.innerHTML += `<option>${s}</option>`);
```

```html
<style>*{font-family:Consolas}</style>
Test Cases: <select id="S" onchange="I.value=this.value,I.oninput()"></select><br><br>
<input id="I" oninput="O.innerText=f(this.value)" size="75">
<pre id="O"></pre>
```