# Expand Emmet HTML Abbreviations

Tags: code-golf, parsing, code-generation

[Emmet](https://emmet.io/) is a text-editor and IDE plugin for writing HTML code using much fewer keypresses. You might think of it like a code-golfing HTML preprocessor. Its syntax is based on CSS selectors.

Your challenge is to [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) an implementation of Emmet. Given some Emmet code, output the resulting HTML.

Note that for the purposes of this challenge, you will not have to handle element "shortcuts" like `bq` → `blockquote` or `a` → `a[href]`. This version of Emmet does not support item numbering. You also do not need to handle the difference between block and inline elements having different spacing.

All elements should have at least one whitespace character (space, tab, newline, whatever) wherever whitespace is shown here, but you don't need to have the indentation shown in the examples.

## Syntax

<sup>(Paraphrased from [Emmet's documentation](https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/))</sup>

Emmet basically just describes an HTML document using syntax similar to CSS selectors. It uses symbols to describe where each element should be placed in the document.

#### Structure operators

- Child: `>`

  ```html
  div>ul>li
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  ```
- Sibling: `+`

  ```html
  div+p+blockquote
  <div></div>
  <p></p>
  <blockquote></blockquote>
  ```
- Put them together:

  ```html
  div+div>p>span+em 
  <div></div>
  <div>
    <p>
      <span></span>
      <em></em>
    </p>
  </div>
  ```
- Climb-up: `^`

  ```html
  div+div>p>span+em^blockquote
  <div></div>
  <div>
    <p>
      <span></span>
      <em></em>
    </p>
    <blockquote></blockquote>
  </div>
  ```

  ```html
  div+div>p>span+em^^blockquote
  <div></div>
  <div>
    <p>
      <span></span>
      <em></em>
    </p>
  </div>
  <blockquote></blockquote>
  ```
- Multiplication: `*`

  ```html
  ul>li*5
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  ```

  ```html
  p>span*2+a
  <p>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <a></a>
  </p>`
  ```

  ```html
  p>span*2^q
  <p>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </p>
  <q></q>
  ```
- Grouping: `()`

  ```html
  div>(header>ul>li*2>a)+footer>p
  <div>
    <header>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </header>
    <footer>
      <p></p>
    </footer>
  </div>
  ```

#### Attribute operators

- ID `#` and class `.`

  ```html
  div#header+div.page+div#footer.class1.class2.class3
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div class="page"></div>
  <div id="footer" class="class1 class2 class3"></div>
  ```
- Custom attributes `[attr]`

  ```html
  td[title="Hello world!" colspan=3]
  <td title="Hello world!" colspan="3"></td>
  ```

  ```html
  td[title=hello colspan=3]
  <td title="hello" colspan="3"></td>
  ```

  ```html
  td[title colspan]
  <td title="" colspan=""></td>
  ```

#### Text

Put text in curly braces:

```html
p{Hello, World!}
<p>Hello, World!</p>
```

```html
a.important[href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"]{click}
<a
  class="important"
  href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"
>
  click
</a>
```

```html
a[href]{click}+b{here}
<a href="">click</a>
<b>here</b>
```

```html
a[href]>{click}+b{here}
<a href="">
  click
  <b>
    here
  </b>
</a>
```

```html
p>{Click}+button{here}+{to continue}
<p>
  Click
  <button>
    here
  </button>
  to continue
</p>
```

```html
p{(a+b)*c>a+b*c}
<p>{(a+b)*c>a+b*c}</p>
```

## Additional test cases

```html
div>p[block]*2>{abc}+span*2{123}+{def}
<div>
  <p block="">
    abc
    <span>123</span>
    <span>123</span>
    def
  </p>
</div>
```

```html
a[href="https://example.com/index.html?a[]={1}&a[]={2}"]{This is an example usage of array parameters "a[]" in url.}
<a href="https://example.com/index.html?a[]={1}&a[]={2}">
  This is an example usage of array parameters "a[]" in url.
</a>
```

---

Your program should give proper output for all of the examples outlined above. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code per language, measured in bytes, wins!

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/122880/108687)

Comment: `div+div>p>span+em^^^bq` seems illegal since it has three `^`s but only two `>`s.

Comment: @Neil Typo, fixed, thanks!

Comment: Can we assume that no `"[]{}` used as literal? For example: `a[href="https://example.com/index.html?a[]={1}&a[]={2}"]{This is an example usage of array parameters "a[]" in url.}` will not be given as input

Comment: ^ Also the `()`: `p{(a+b)*c>a+b*c}` for example.

Comment: The rule of `*` is confusing. As your example, `ul>li*2>a` means 2 `a`s in each `li`. So I would wonder how it associated with other operators. What are expected output for `p>span*2+a`, `p>span*2+a`, `p>span*2*2`, `p>span*2^q`, `p>span*2.red`, `p>a*2[href]`?

Comment: @tsh No, `ul>li*2>a` means 2 `li`s each with an `a`. Of your examples, only `p>span*2+a` and `p>span*2^q` are valid input; I'll add test cases for them now. Attributes won't come after the repetition, and the same element won't have multiple repetitons.

Comment: @tsh I'm going to say no, you can't assume that. I'll add a test case for that

Comment: maybe you forgot to duplicate the p in new testcase

Comment: Your `a*2>b` has 2 bs, but `a*2+b` has only one. So what about `a*2>b^i`?

Comment: Your `a[href]>{click}` have no space before `click` ,but `p[block]*2>{abc }` have extra spaces before `abc`. What is the rule of space?

Comment: @tsh Well, HTML whitespacing is weird and depends on a lot of things so I'm going to just change the rule to "put at least 1 whitespace everywhere" since that's what all the answers already do and I don't really know how to explain how it technically would work. I probably should've sandboxed this :/

Comment: @tsh `a*2>b^i` gives `<a> <b></b> </a> <a> <b></b> </a> <i></i>`. But I realize how that causes confusion, I definitely should have given more test cases for `*` since it seems to be screwing up some submissions

Comment: @Arnauld That  was probably a copy-paste mistake, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 465 bytes

```
\^+
$&+
+`([^>]+>((\()|(?<-3>\))|(?(3)>)|[^()>])+(?(3)^))\^
($1)
\)|$
/$&
{%`^( *[^()>+]+)\*(\d+)(.*)
$2*$($1$3¶)
G`.
%`^(( *)((\()|(?<-4>\))|(?(4)[>+])|[^()>+])+(?(4)^))\+
$1/¶$2
%`^( *)(((\()|(?<-4>\))|(?(4)[>+])|[^()>+])+(?(4)^))\>(.+)
$1$2¶  $1$5¶$1/$2
)%`^( *)\((.+)\)/$
$1$2
%`^( *)((/|())\w+)(.*?)(/)?$
$1<$2>$#4*$5$#6*$(</$2>
>#(\w+)
 id="$1">
+`>\.(\w+)
 class="$1">
+`(class=".+)" class="
$1 
]
 ]
+`>\[(\w+)(="([^"]*)"|=([^ ]*))? 
 $1="$3$4">[
[]{[]|}/?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZPNjpswFIX3fgpKPCMbtyBCUqnVYBZdTLezmkr8KAQ8AxoSKDGDKshr5QHyYum1SSZVW1XqytfnfvccX6K0Qpbb1D3dkPvVKUoYwrcMsRUJEx4zTkhE6EiCuw8ej6iqiEc5HcOEUB5Tpu8JpVGCCHYpiuiIkYNv0XCzSohhaY7FjEYWiXJGiW1RhOcWBhp7xwNF9ysbKRZgek1bXNIWNIT5cyCbEhc6EV7qOscDnqMpCqb/Z5wTm8FTXDw/HgwDziV4uQ7Y0bNfRBQSUQdr7BrjjAQMer1NQIlDA0Xc4TnHs4WFl3j2ERa8Ay@O@IwoEhll7pvYNTl8Wx7ZZzGr0t3uTSfnK6SalxYYGyhGRqznQj1HfBN@HjO2qDn6UBlQ0cBAsAV4eXhh8hCF8RDG494J0Amj4@GUl6@8q3hVIqhYw9ZVnb1872optKDaDd816ZaJzZ9K8i88@bWrM6ylojgpRJqLdsq15jyl7KkGqOWN6s@mtjKzm/RZqGI2AbZe352O@XR4SOahLGUlfPOrqKra6Ou2yt/Bt6or9RTfi69IoYm/dC5ajJpB27w3HrXPHqV2uWnqVqZbGRatePLNQspm99lx@r63f9Sd7NbCzuqN06cyK4JXP3/oF/2nx@dv2YMZD1lVZi9go4cvV7YeCtGKN5n/rjd8@KIUA6ROyno76WwwpFpgC//PTux/Ag) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
\^+
$&+
```

Add a `+` after any `^`s.

```
+`([^>]+>((\()|(?<-3>\))|(?(3)>)|[^()>])+(?(3)^))\^
($1)
```

Convert `^`s into the equivalent brackets.

```
\)|$
/$&
```

Innermost elements should be on a single line.

```
{`
)`
```

Process as much as possible.

```
%`^( *[^()>+]+)\*(\d+)(.*)
$2*$($1$3¶)
G`.
```

Process multiplications.

```
%`^(( *)((\()|(?<-4>\))|(?(4)[>+])|[^()>+])+(?(4)^))\+
$1/¶$2
```

Process siblings.

```
%`^( *)(((\()|(?<-4>\))|(?(4)[>+])|[^()>+])+(?(4)^))\>(.+)
$1$2¶  $1$5¶$1/$2
```

Process children, appending a closing tag after them.

```
%`^( *)\((.+)\)/$
$1$2
```

Unwrap lines starting and ending in brackets.

```
%`^( *)((/|())\w+)(.*?)(/)?$
$1<$2>$#4*$5$#6*$(</$2>
```

Surround tags with `<>`s, removing attributes from closing tags, and add closing tags for single-line tags.

```
>#(\w+)
 id="$1">
```

Process ids.

```
+`>\.(\w+)
 class="$1">
+`(class=".+)" class="
$1
```

Process classes.

```
]
 ]
+`>\[(\w+)(="([^"]*)"|=([^ ]*))? 
 $1="$3$4">[
```

Process attributes. I can do this on one line but it turns out to be a byte longer.

```
[]{[]|}/?
```

Remove the remaining syntax.

Answer (score 3):

## Python3, 1152 bytes:

```py
import re
R=re.findall
def U(t):
 [N]=R('^\w+',t);n='<'+N
 if(i:=R('(?<=#)\w+',t)):n+=f' id="{i[0]}"'
 if(c:=R('(?<=\.)\w+',t)):n+=' class="'+' '.join(c)+'"'
 if(a:=R('(?<=\[)[^\]]+',t)):n+=' '+' '.join(i+'=""'if'='not in i else re.sub('(?<=\=)[^"]+',lambda x:f'"{x.group()}"',i)for i in R('(?:\w+\="[^"]+")+|(?:\w+\=[^\s\]]+)+|\w+',a[0]))
 e=''
 if(o:=re.findall('(?<=\{)[^\}]+',t)):e=o[0]+' '
 return n+'>'+e,f'</{N}>'
F=lambda t,I:t if type(t)==list else '  '*I+''.join(U(t))
def f(s,I,c,l):
 if'('==s[0]:s.pop(0);t=[];f(s,I+1,t,[]);s.insert(0,t);
 t=s.pop(0)
 if')'!=t:
  if[]!=s:
   S=s.pop(0)
   if')'==S:c.append('  '*I+f'<{t}></{t}>')
   if'>'==S:Q,W=U(t);C=[];c.append(T:=['  '*I+Q,C,'  '*I+W]);l.append(T);f(s,I+1,C,l)
   if'+'==S:C=[];f(s,I,C,l);c.append(F(t,I));c.extend(C)
   if'^'==S[0]:c.append(F(t,I));C=[];f(s,len(l)-len(S),C,l);l[-len(S)].extend(C)
   if'*'==S:x=s.pop(0);s.insert(0,t);C=[];f(s,I,C,l);c.extend(T:=[C for _ in range(int(x))])
  else:Q,W=U(t);c.append('  '*I+Q+W)
P=lambda x:'\n'.join(i if type(i)==str else P(i)for i in x)
def M(s):S=R('\>|\+|\*|\+|\^+|\(|\)|[^(?:\>\+\*\+\^\(\))]+',s);l,c=[],[];f(S,0,c,l);return P(c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVVbb9s2GH3Xr2CUB5KmqrlNBwxyqD0YKJaHBkm9Ig@6DLJExVwZShXp1oXj356R1CVeA3jtHiRR5DlH53z8aLff9KaRF7@13dMTf2ibToOOeR9ox8Kay6oQwqtYDT4ijSMPJNcZ/YBgnn4lMNB4ISm8hOTaA7xGPLJL6PdLeo6HdRxJQmsIeEX9PU/m2cGHDltO2DT8FxiCUhRKUR8SCGD4d8MlKjGBA6945iU4ydMsO6YecTiB1PchryGFstGAS8ABE4qZdKHargcRakR8qyGKh3VVgF1UQ3@/C@@7ZtsibOwGHNdNZ8hGwX06MnZT6juej8njOGPcKOvHTLlAhYmLsQcYhb33Jjoq6vD9vQ1xGEMw2hiSDeEZm3rbSSAJjCFhQQ0vf9lfH2LovaODVx1cRSZYDfS3lpntoVRwpfuQEAA4uyJwqIbdPez2sUYquArKQNjdNNVBkFJlPhqpsG1aNMcLTZNs4WDkdaCDJMMLFXKpWKfR3O65BzQd0U4DwzOqjZwZJ9kZVXYIVkcY0KMoXUVlWLQtkxUaHJpce32ITThzhyM2dtjb4I5a54ultTQx/4xoMrBvg2UwDO@MTzFB8JRgaaIOqsSpLqd8bu1Z9x0yFcV2gu20nViOxNwSbZFeYCcxwSQS@JV9rHAvLJLhNXshOHNOdlOJvqvwS4uDgI2@BLYf/7L92BXyniEuNdphnFlxu/nPdfu@2LfkDns3dOp1mMrxuEx9xE0fKd31bXSDjrp/13fQe6RwtLLHMI0fU9PsM3fPzYUeU/yY5PZExClJZ@bKU5Qab6bBlalIUJpkgQu3CuauDRdDo9@YY/7UdjbMewQr/iXeilhwaPq2n4Wv4OztfHzrMaQla9GUnz5vG83@A2ol21i1hSTs4Wew@f/7RJ6vP5/Au3SzX08rxmjDiop1fS1mb@ICk7oxRrq4Pc0874nWUtgW98wOzntq6H5hX/ePN/3j4oSarhLNtWDU/4MJ0YCvTSeqMx@UjbBR6UX2I@SN4/4UZ0SfwrZ7ZyoAd87V4QS0CPv/t0LqZNOxmvqFqmpV@Nm@FLz8dJLrGCOQrPcb1rEfJ8QvCM760i4Cs7rVupEOArQtktRcbh386R8)

Comment: Note that the indentation is actually optional, there just has to be at least one whitespace character wherever I showed whitespace in the examples. Will try to emphasize this a bit more in the post.

Comment: -2 bytes by moving the `e=''` line in `U` to the declaration, and removing the space between `else` and `'` in `F`

Comment: Doesn't work on the last test case

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 425 bytes

```javascript
i=>(s=i.match(/\w+|"[^"]*"|\{[^}]*\}|\S/g),S=_=>L=s.shift()||"",U=_=>s.unshift(L)&&"",T=v=>S()==v?' ':U(),D=c=>T`#`?' id='+S()+D(c):T`.`?D(c+(c&&' ')+S()):T`[`?A()+D(c):c&&` class="${c}"`,A=_=>T`]`?'':' '+S()+(T`=`?L+S():'=""')+A(),W=_=>S()[0]=="{"?L.slice(1,-1):U(),P=(r='',l=W()||(T`(`?P()+T`)`:T`^`?U():(r=`</${S()}> `,` <${L}${D('')}>`+W())))=>Array(T`*`?-~S():2).join(l+W()+(T`>`&&P()+(T`^`&&U(L='+')))+r)+(T`+`&&P()))()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVTRbts2FH33V7BMYJGWIs/O@jC3lBA0D33wQ4o4yABbHhmJjtjSkipSdgJZ@/XsUlrabR1qGODVOeeee0le8LM4CJPWqrIXRZnJl0rURiL2olhEDFPhXtg0J9PN0T/h9RYnE3zatOttl0w23WlzO32kwS37g0VLZkKTq50l9HTCOLhzoAmbYgCXdDwGdMUOLLollLFD7CFvcUdocM1SFq34GQdEZczzgfevSUoXKx7yGCKfpOMxyKmjHLzm8dWrCCiOUi2MYfi8TTvMgytXe8UTcPQWkNc7khVnPF66eOExjMENPIJ7pwVs/UvCGG5xvAyNVqkks@BiRvsGbxipmecFmt27zYER4fENWK445dDNlscgW4CIv5@et2DWRYgHHL0/b5fdeXtNPA8g7kM6/Fh0VdfiGWwmPL740/Uzp@HnUhVEO4nrNOLj8c0QbiG8I0s4Fw@S/boH/YGnlNAXK41NhZEGMcRHmTpEjY60cpFf@Q@6TL98bUore8DRVWQqUfhy/yOy/Zl8@0@2rzF529cjuRSZrIe6k3kkqL8rQVRHlePPBtqZhZV4lC44GwRhf3GzYZkPy@XIZmurrJYMf5Ral@hY1jp7g1FaatcKu0y@S/Je8T/MK5aMqra3CdB979ONRKj2VVlbUdh1Xssdw7m1lVlMp8fjMXwuG9s8yDAt99Ojm/74wLJPx1@Pv90//p5@wkmbwoB8AZs@@fXTf2hzWctvcPRfvIraDw5BADXWlsWA@y2ybgOFVUUDsv7I1/1JJ3CWrXhIIcPtZDJv0Wx@6TIyuXst9L15@ST2lR4aV0Umn8Lc7nUs1glrZ924X@cd9L/KlUHwFwX6Owc1Bi4GlTsk3GwieAXEXsIFGYQhDyNVoKbWYTfioa3VntDQVFpZ4m0Kj74bfZtBeC8q8oRYhNoRcrsyJXSky0fyBLJ/I/1TA/gPBAAdfffyFw)

Following commented code based on a previous version:

```javascript
i=>(
  // tokenize the input
  //   <word>: \w+
  //   <string>: "[^"]*"
  //   <text>: \{[^}]*\}
  //   other operator: \S
  s=i.match(/\w+|"[^"]*"|\{[^}]*\}|\S/g),
  // parse the input
  P())
// Get first token, the token is consumed
S=_=>L=s.shift()||""
// Undo last get, the token is placed back
U=_=>s.unshift(L)&&""
// Test if next token is given value
// Consume the token and return truthy whitespace string if match
// Or return falsy empty string if not match
T=v=>S()==v?' ':U()
// P (whole program) ::= V "+" P | V ">" P (lookahead != "^") | V ">" P "^" P | <empty>
// V (an HTML tag) ::= <text> | "(" P ")" | <word> D | V "*" <word>
P=(
  // right part
  r='',
  // left part
  l=
    W()|| // V -> <text>
    (T`(`?P()+T`)`: // V -> "(" P ")"
     T`^`?U(): // reduce
     (r=`</${S()}> `,` <${L}${D``}>`+W())) // V -> <word> D
)=>
  T`+`?l+r+P(): // P -> V "+" P
  T`>`?l+P()+r+(T`^`&&P()): // P -> V ">" P ["^" P]?
  T`*`?Array(-~S()).join(P(r,l)): // V -> V "*" <word>
  l+r // reduce
// D (all atributes) ::= "#" <word> | "." <word> | "[" A | <empty>
D=c=> // `c` is all class names collected yet
  T`#`?' id='+S()+D(c): // D -> "#" <word> D
  T`.`?D(c+' '+S()): // D -> "." <word> D
  T`[`?A()+D(c): // D -> "[" A D
  c+c&&` class="${c}"` // reduce
// A (`[]` style attributes) ::= <word> A | <word> "=" <word> A | <word> "=" <string> A | "]"
A=_=>
  T`]`?'': // "]"
  ' '+S()+(T`=`?L+S():'=""')+A() // <word> ["=" (<word> | <string>)]? A
// W slice <text> to remove "{}" or return empty string if next token is not <text>
W=_=>S()[0]=="{"?L.slice(1,-1):U()
```